# Moving Blobstore to GCS: Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

Here is my existing py code for data uploading to **blobstore**.

```
from google.appengine.api import files

def save_data_to_blob_store(data):
    # Create the file
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')

    # Open the file and write to it
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(data)

    # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
    files.finalize(file_name)

    # Get the file's blob key
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
    return str(blob_key)
```

Now i'm trying to deprecate blobstore & moving to **GCS**. I wrote some code but not working as expected.

```
def save_data_to_gcs(request):
    file_name = '/gs/bucket-name-1/new_file' # change bucket/object names to suit your needs
    writable_file_name = files.gs.create(file_name, mime_type='application/octet-stream',
                                     acl='public-read')
    with files.open(writable_file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write('Hello World!\n')
        f.write('This is a Google Cloud Storage object!\n')
    files.finalize(writable_file_name)
```

While executing this procedure, GAE throwing an error on production as,

```
Exception in request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bfsolu/248.371810019093562707/common/zip-packages/django-1.1.zip/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bfsolu/248.371810019093562707/myapp/utils.py", line 51, in save_data_to_gcs
    acl='public-read')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/gs.py", line 326, in create
    return files._create(_GS_FILESYSTEM, filename=filename, params=params)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 647, in _create
    _make_call('Create', request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 252, in _make_call
    _raise_app_error(e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 210, in _raise_app_error
    raise PermissionDeniedError(e)
 PermissionDeniedError: ApplicationError: 8
```

Any one could help to correct me in **save_data_to_gcs** procedure, Would appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you activated GCS (enabled billing, etc)?

In Google Cloud Console, did you give your app access to your bucket? To do that, select your bucket, click 'Bucket Permissions', and add new 'User' permissions, providing your app email address (app-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) and making it an owner.

Comment: @MarkSimpson: Thanks buddy..Its works like charm..
I need one more favour, How to get unique key of files record?

Comment: OK, I've turned my comment into an answer below. Please accept it as correct. Post that new question separately. It is unrelated to this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to [activate your project](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate) for GCS.

Then grant your app permission to use your bucket in [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console):

To do that, select your bucket, click the 'Bucket Permissions' button, and add new 'User' permissions, providing your app email address (app-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) and making it an owner.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working anymore as the files api was shutdown in September 2015.